# Do the datasets/dataframes inside a package also get loaded automatically by the 'library' function?

Tags: r

I see that I don't need to execute `data(murders)` to load the dataset ***murders*** after I've executed `library(dslabs)`.

Here ***murders*** is a dataset inside the package ***dslabs***.

If the answer is **Yes**, then isn't this an inefficient use of memory - we are loading all the datasets in a package automatically, while we may not use even one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> isn't this an inefficient use of memory

No, because R packages support an automatic mechanism called *lazy loading* (which you can manually use yourself via the [`lazyLoad` function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lazyload.html), though this is rarely useful since packages can do it automatically).

This means that, once the package is attached, you can access the variable name `murders`, but before accessing that name for the first time it’s not actually loaded into memory.

Comment: Just to be clear on this - I haven't used the lazyload function, so in my case that isn't happening; am I right?

Comment: @HemanthBakaya No, I need to rephrase this: packages do this automatically (subject to the info in mrhellmann’s answer).

Answer (score 3):

From Hadley's r-pkgs (http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html):

> If the DESCRIPTION contains LazyData: true, then datasets will be lazily loaded. This means that they won’t occupy any memory until you use them.

So no, the data isn't loaded until it is explicitly called for (in most packages).

Comment: What is 'DESCRIPTION'?

Comment: @HemanthBakaya Read all about the description file here: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html